# Loop and Condition in C#

Tags: loops

Very new to C# and still learning. Here's a loop and Condition I would like to create:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyLoop
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int LineA = 4;
            int LineB = 200;
            int LineC = 10;
            int LineD = 3600;
            int X;
            int Y;

            //X is equals to: Add LineA number to the LineD number
            //Y is equals to:  Add LineB number to the LineC number
            //Condition:
            //Is X is greater  than Y? 
            //Answer: No then
            //Is X is equal to Y?
            //Answer: No then
            //Keep lopping until it matches to the Y and then stop.
            //So what will be final number/value for both X and Y?


        }
    }
}
```

How do I put into C# code?

Can Someone help me to start? I am really confused of where to start..

Comment: This is a very basic programming excercise, all possible with a simple `while` loop and some `if` statements, I suggest reading up a little more on basic C# programming tutorials.

Comment: You may want to start with some introductory tutorials on C#.  Perhaps a beginner book on the subject might help.  Loops and conditionals are *guaranteed* to be covered in any introduction to *any* language.

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this. You can Google `for`, `while`, and `do-while` loops in C#. Also, your algorithm made no sense to me, because you haven't mentioned how you're updating the `LineABCD` variables every time the loop runs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a beginner but you can use this as a base to your code. The thing is that X is greater than Y so that should be the output result.

```
 int LineA, LineB, LineC, LineD;
        LineA = 4;
        LineB = 200;
        LineC = 10;
        LineD = 3600;

        int X;
        int Y;

        X = LineA + LineD;
        Y = LineB + LineC;

        if (X > Y)
            Console.WriteLine("X is greater than y");
        else if(X==Y)
            Console.WriteLine("X is equal to y");
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you all for your contribution. I am stuck where I need to create a loop keep adding and compare until one of the statements become true.